# Creating Instances and types in Azure TimeSeriesInsights

Tags: azure, time-series, azure-timeseries-insights

I am new in TimeSeriesInsights. Imagine we a have smart meter which transmits different types of telemetry data such as `Consumption`, `Indoor Temperature` etc. Structure of the messages is the same but a `type` property is there to distinguish between different telemetry types.

How can I created TSI Instances & Types?

One type per each telemetry type? Then how to distinguish them from each other?

I'd appreciate if anyone experienced, walk me through the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how last-first might give you the consumption! I would be interested to know more.
However you could trying modeling an aggregate variable in TSI
[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVEWV.png).
Here is the corresponding documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/concepts-variables

Comment: Thanks. I used `max($event['reading'].Long)-min($event['reading'].Long)` to calculate consumption. Smart meters readings are transmitted to the IotHub almost every few minutes and the readings are always growing like 100, 150, 300, 500 etc. What I need is to calculate consumptions every 15 minutes which would result in for example (150-100=50), (300-150=150), (500-300=200). So last reading minus first reading in each interval results in consumption in that period of time. I hope I have my point clear.

Comment: Still I am trying to see of this is the right way to calculate the consumption (the delta from the readings)

Comment: @Mori, I guess it would work. However please be aware the interval over which max and min is picked from, is the user chosen interval in TSI. Its not the interval for which the smartmeter sends data in every payload ! But the logic what you are applying would work!

Answer (score 0):

@Mori, Thankyou for choosing TimeSeries Insights. By types I mean you are referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/concepts-model-overview#time-series-model-types.  These types cant be automatically created based on a type field sent in the JSON payload. Typically customers create them using the TSI explorer or use our API to create them using scripts. I am happy to walk you through the type creation and assignment process. Please let me a good time to connect.

Comment: Thanks! Are you a MSFT? I could find my way a bit into the topic. We are receiving smart meters readings continuously. Is it possible to create a custom variable in a Type that calculate the consumption (delta of reading)? I mean Last Reading minus First Reading in each interval?